# Parse mathematical expressions with pyparsing

Tags: python-3.x, pyparsing

I'm trying to parse a mathematical expression using pyparsing. I know i could just copy the example calculator from pyparsing site, but i want to understand it so i can add to it later. And i'm here because i tried to understand the example, and i couldn't, so i tried my best, and i got to this:

```
symbol = (
    pp.Literal("^") |
    pp.Literal("*") |
    pp.Literal("/") |
    pp.Literal("+") |
    pp.Literal("-")
)
operation = pp.Forward()
atom = pp.Group(
    pp.Literal("(").suppress() + operation + pp.Literal(")").suppress()
) | number
operation << (pp.Group(number + symbol + number + pp.ZeroOrMore(symbol + atom)) | atom)
expression = pp.OneOrMore(operation)


print(expression.parseString("9-1+27+(3-5)+9"))
```

That prints:

```
[[9, '-', 1, '+', 27, '+', [[3, '-', 5]], '+', 9]]
```

It works, kinda. I want precedence and all sorted into `Groups`, but after trying a lot, i couldn't find a way to do it. More or less like this:

```
[[[[9, '-', 1], '+', 27], '+', [3, '-', 5]], '+', 9]
```

I want to keep it AST-looking, i would like to generate code from it.

I did saw the `operatorPrecedence` class? similar to `Forward`, but i don't think i understand how it works either.

EDIT:

Tried more in depth `operatorPrecedence` and i got this:

```
expression = pp.operatorPrecedence(number, [
    (pp.Literal("^"), 1, pp.opAssoc.RIGHT),
    (pp.Literal("*"), 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT),
    (pp.Literal("/"), 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT),
    (pp.Literal("+"), 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT),
    (pp.Literal("-"), 2, pp.opAssoc.LEFT)
])
```

Which doesn't handle parenthesis (i don't know if i will have to postprocess the results) and i need to handle them.

Comment: `operatorPrecedence` handles ()'s internally, test it and see.

Comment: True ;)  I tested it with a complicated expression and it was too nested to actually see it worked.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The actual name for this parsing problem is "infix notation" (and in recent versions of pyparsing, I am renaming `operatorPrecedence` to `infixNotation`).  To see the typical implementation of infix notation parsing, look at the fourFn.py example on the pyparsing wiki.  There you will see an implementation of this simplified BNF to implement 4-function arithmetic, with precedence of operations:

```
operand :: integer or real number
factor :: operand | '(' expr ')'
term :: factor ( ('*' | '/') factor )*
expr :: term ( ('+' | '-') term )*
```

So an expression is one or more terms separated by addition or subtraction operations.

A term is one or more factors separated by multiplication or division operations.

A factor is either a lowest-level operand (in this case, just integers or reals), OR an expr enclosed in ()'s.

Note that this is a recursive parser, since factor is used indirectly in the definition of expr, but expr is also used to define factor.

In pyparsing, this looks roughly like this (assuming that integer and real have already been defined):

```
LPAR,RPAR = map(Suppress, '()')
expr = Forward()
operand = real | integer
factor = operand | Group(LPAR + expr + RPAR)
term = factor + ZeroOrMore( oneOf('* /') + factor )
expr <<= term + ZeroOrMore( oneOf('+ -') + term )
```

Now using `expr`, you can parse any of these:

```
3
3+2
3+2*4
(3+2)*4
```

The `infixNotation` pyparsing helper method takes care of all the recursive definitions and groupings, and lets you define this as:

```
expr = infixNotation(operand,
        [
        (oneOf('* /'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
        (oneOf('+ -'), 2, opAssoc.LEFT),
        ])
```

But this obscures all the underlying theory, so if you are trying to understand how this is implemented, look at the raw solution in fourFn.py.

[EDIT - 18 Dec 2022] For those looking for a pre-defined solution, I've packaged `infixNotation` up into its own pip-installable package called [plusminus](https://pypi.org/project/plusminus/). `plusminus` defines a `BaseArithmeticParser` class for creating a ready-to-run parser and evaluator that supports these operators:

```
  **   ÷   >=  ∈  in   ?:
  *    +   ==  ∉  not  |absolute-value|
  //   -   !=  ∩  and
  /    <   ≠   ∪  ∧
  mod  >   ≤   &  or
  ×    <=  ≥   |  ∨
```

And these functions:

```
  abs    ceil   max
  round  floor  str
  trunc  min    bool
```

The `BaseArithmeticParser` class allows you to define additional operators and functions for your own domain-specific expressions, and the examples show how to define parsers with custom functions and operators for dice rolling, retail price discounts, among others.

Comment: So, did i understand right that `infixNotation` is a generic form of defining grammars like mine? The BNF example can then be implemented using `infixNotation`?

Comment: There is one hitch with `infixNotation`, and that is that order of operations for exponentiation is right-to-left instead of left-to-right, and simply marking it with `opAssoc.RIGHT` doesn't fully handle things. Even Python's internal parser for arithmetic strings has to treat exponentiation as a special case. Also, if you find your list of operation precedences getting very deep, performance may start to suffer - in this case, read up on `ParserElement.enablePackrat` to speed things back up.

Comment: Also, you have incorrectly given `+` higher precedence than `-`, and `*` higher than `/` when they should be equal. That`s why I use `oneOf("+ -")` for the addition operations and `oneOf("* /")` for the multiplication operations. This is significant, since what you have now will always evaluate `+` before `-`, even if out of left-to-right order. Check out `7 + 2 - 3 + 5` - what you have will give higher precedence to addition over subtraction, as in `(7+2) - (3+5)`, value of 1, when it should be just straight left-to-right evaluation giving 11.

Comment: Oh, so `oneOf` tests for both values itself, instad of letting `infixNotation` doing it. So many tricky things too look after :)

Comment: `oneOf('+ -')` is just shorthand for `Literal("+") | Literal("-")`. The point is, both '+' and '-' are checked at the same time instead of at 2 different levels in the precedence-of-operations list passed to `infixNotation`.

Comment: Thanks for the proposed edit by Daewon Lee that got rejected - it was legit after all. Also, my earlier cautions about exponentiation can be easily addressed post-parsing. Simply mark the `'**'` operator as `opAssoc.LEFT` associative, but at eval time, evaluate the operands right-to-left. The packrat parsing comment still holds though.